# How to execute code from string in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, exec, dynamic-compilation

I have simple code snippet from outside (backend server), basically simple mathematics, which I want to execute in Windows store/Windows phone universal application. This code changes state of static fields of one of my classes (set its values to some numbers).
Is there any way to execute code from string in Windows Store / UWP app?
 I know about CSharpCodeProvider, but it seems absent in UWP. Just like most useful things.

Comment: Such an Eval() feature is always dangerous, that's why it's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any out-of-the-box way, other than using `Reflection`, but this might be tricky.

I've been experimenting with [this](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-Expression.NET) a while back, but haven't done much in-depth testing. It's definitely enough for simple expressions and seems to have better performance than just using `Reflection`.

Comment: I can't say I agree with everything you say and, you can evaluate strings up to 50 chars for free, and as far as I know there is no easy way to do it without third-party